# Model find returning all rows in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This problem has me very stumped and I hope you can help me out.

I have a model in CakePHP (2.x) that references another model like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('MyClass2', 'Model');
class MyClass1 extends AppModel {
```

Later in the class, I call `find('all')` on `MyClass2`:

```
$params = array(
    'MyClass2.user_id' => $user_id
);
$my_class2 = new MyClass2();
$data = $my_class2->find('all', $params);
```

But instead of returning only the rows that match `$user_id`, it returns every row in the database. I can confirm that `$user_id` is being saved in the database correct and is initialized correctly, but it still always returns all the data instead of only the rows that match `$user_id`. What should I do to get the data from `MyClass2` inside of `MyClass1` that only matched the correct `$user_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `conditions` array in params :)

```
$params = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'MyClass2.user_id' => $user_id
    )
);
```

Comment: Ack! I can't believe I forgot that! Thanks for catching my error. :)